# How can I determine in VSTS why a Build Agent is unavailable?

Tags: azure-pipelines, alm

In VSTS, I have a Build triggered, but it's not started.  A message indicates:

> Waiting for an available agent

I've ensured that my agent:

- is Running
- is Enabled
- has Capabilities for any Demands defined in the Build Definition.

You can see from this screenshot that there are Agents that will run this build, but I've disabled them.  There is another Agent, not listed among the "possible agents", that I would expect to be here.

[image]

My question is, how can I see what is disqualifying my Agent for consideration?  Are there undisclosed demands that I'm not seeing, etc?

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the error message?

Comment: I've since gotten this working by installing Visual Studio on the build server.  I guess even though there are no explicit "demands" set on the Build Definition, VSTS is smart enough to know the Agent doesn't have capabilities that it will need (for a specific .NET version for example).  It would be nice to have it notify you what the missing dependency is though.

Comment: By default, if the demands don't meet the request, it will prompt the dialog to notification. Since your original issue has been solved, you can post an answer and accept it as answer.